# How do I set a relative position for a Qt widget?

Tags: qt

I've been searching around and reading docs about moving widgets around, but I'm still looking for a good example.

I have a widget that I display with a hotkey, and I'd like it to popup somewhere else in the MainWindow rather than the center. If I use move(), then the widget remains in that position regardless if it's parent window changes position. I'd like the widget to be placed in a location inside of the parent widget so that when moving the parent widget, it stays in the relative position. How can I go about doing this?

I read about MapToParent, but I'm not sure how to use this. I tried:

```
QPoint fD_p = fDialog->pos();
QPoint parent_fD_p = QWidget::mapToParent(fD_p);
fDialog->move(parent_fD_p);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reimplement the move event handler in your parent widget  `void QWidget::moveEvent ( QMoveEvent * event )` and probably the resize event handler.

In these event handlers you can recalculate the new position for your widget and then move it.

`mapToParent` and `mapFromParent` methods translate relative coordinates. From the documentation:

```
QPoint QWidget::mapFromParent ( const QPoint & pos ) const
Translates the parent widget coordinate pos to widget coordinates.

Same as mapFromGlobal() if the widget has no parent.
```